# how to use JSON in clientside only

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have created an Object.. please tell me If I'm doing it right:

```
{"images": {

    image1 : {
        "small_image" : "images/1.png",
        "large_image" : "images/big/1.png"
    },

    image2 : {
        "small_image" : "images/2.png",
        "large_image" : "images/big/2.png"
    },

    image3 : {
        "small_image" : "images/3.png",
        "large_image" : "images/big/3.png"
    },

}
```

Now, I saved it with the name **images.json**

How will I call it on my HTML file using jQuery?.. 
I want to test it on a console first..

I use this code and it does'nt display anthing on console..

```
$.getJSON("js/images.json", function(data){
   $.each(data, function (index, value) {
     console.log("asdfasdf " +value);
   });
});
```

Comment: Every key needs to be double quoted, you also have a comma after the last image element which is not valid. you can use jsonlint to test things: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I'd recommend making those images into an array instead of named keys  `image1`, `image2`, and so on.

Comment: @Plynx, what do you mean?.. I'll just removed the image1, image2, image3 ?

Comment: @prodigitalson, thanks for jsonlint.com ,that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify your object Literal to make it a JSON String. It should look more like this:

```
{"images": {

    "image1" : {
        "small_image" : "images/1.png",
        "large_image" : "images/big/1.png"
    },

    "image2" : {
        "small_image" : "images/2.png",
        "large_image" : "images/big/2.png"
    },

    "image3" : {
        "small_image" : "images/3.png",
        "large_image" : "images/big/3.png"
    }

}}
```

That along with the javascript you already have should work, assuming your webserver is setup to properly serve .json files.

Comment: already done that.. does't display anything on console either.

Comment: add an error callback, what does it's 3rd argument tell you? (`$.getJSON(...).fail(function(){ console.log(arguments) });`)